# Foxpro is returning a date type indication for a non-existing date

Tags: visual-foxpro

If you run the following function in the command box it returns a [D] when it should return a [U]. Because April 31, 1964 is not a valid date. Is this because 1964 is a leap year? Is this a bug?

? Type('DATE(Val(Substr([19640430],1,4)),Val(Substr([19640430],5,2)),Val(Substr([19640430],7,2)) + 1)')

Any information on this would be very helpful.

Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

It is because, even it is empty, a Date datatype would return D. In your case, it returns empty, because Date(1964, 4, 31) is not a valid date. It may or may not be documented, I don't know, in Date() functions, second parameter is checked if it is in the range 1-12, and 3rd parameter is checked to be in 1-31. That is it, other than that, non-existing dates do not cause an error but simply return an empty date, but still it is a DATE.

You might try:

```
? Date(2000,2,29)
? Date(2001,2,29)
* or even
? Date(2020,2,31)
```

Last two wouldn't error but return empty "DATE".

If you are doing the type check for date's validity, then better check it being not empty.

Comment: You are correct that it counts the day 31 of the month as correct number of days for any month, in this evaluation. What does work is reassembling the date in the correct order and evaluating whether CTOD() of it is empty. CTOD() is passed through the date disambiguation system were TYPE() is not. Two different set of rules here. And CTOD() is blazingly fast. So this is a complete victory.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. TYPE() is working right, exactly as it should as explained above. You can use Date() or Ctod() for checking  it. In case of CTOD() be sure you are using strict date format.

Comment: I am a huge Foxpro fan for over 20 years. Your answers are spot on and I would like to work with you someday.

Answer (score 0):

```
Procedure VDATE
    Lparameters v1, v2, v3

    v1 = Str(v1,4,0)

    v2 = str2(v2)

    If Len(v2) < 2
        v2 = [0] + v2
    Endif

    v3 = str2(v3)

    If Len(v3) < 2
        v3 = [0] + v3
    Endif

    Do Case
        Case Empty(Ctod(v2 + [/] + v3 + [/] + v1))
            Return .F.
        Case Ctod(v2 + [/] + v3 + [/] + v1) > Date()
            Return .F.
        Case Ctod(v2 + [/] + v3 + [/] + v1) < Ctod([01/01/1000])
            Return .F.
        Otherwise
            Return .T.
    Endcase
```

Comment: It is for a history website that I am have created. It will be up on Monday. timelinesinhistory.com